# Join tables that contain no relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following database:

[image]

1. Table Messages:

   - Responsible for storing messages sent do different email addresses.
2. Table Emails:

   - Only responsible for storing email addresses (primary key = Email) 
     (toEmail has a relationship with table emails) (Sotres Foo@gmail.com, Foo2@gmail.com etc...)
3. Table Contacts:

   - Used to store user's contacts. (stores mark, John, Tom, etc...)
4. Table ContactEmails

   - Need this table because a contact may have multiple email addresses. (Stores the ids found in table Emails)

**Anyways here is the question:**
I want to create a query that will select all the messages that are sent during specific dates. **I want to include the contact name in the query if it exists**. I have crated the following query but it is to slow:

```
Func<string, Contact> tryGetContact = (email)=>{
    var contactEmail = db.ContactEmails.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.IdEmail==email);
    if(contactEmail==null)
       return null;
    return contactEmail.Contact; // navigational property created by entity framework.
};

var query = from msg in db.Messages
            join email in db.Emails on msg.ToEmail equals email.Email
            where msg.Date < "some date" && msg.Date > "some other date" 
            select new
            {
                MessageSubject = msg.Subject,
                ToEmail = email.Email,
                Contact = tryGetContact(email.Email) // this slows down the query!
            };
```

In order to make my query execute faster do I need to store all the contacts in a dictionary and separate this query into 2 queries?

Storing all the contacts in a dictionary will make things much more efficient. But retriving all the contacts from the database where I do not need most of them makes me feel I am wasting resources.

Comment: Are you using a server based database like MS SQL server? If so, it will be quicker to do the query you want with a stored procedure or query directly.

Comment: Is `ContactEmails.IdEmail` indexed in your database? Regardless of how you write your request, you aren't going to get good performance if you don't at least have that index defined.

Comment: Yes I only have one MS SQL server database. The problem is that sometimes I send a message to an email address that belongs to no contact. That's why I do not have that relationship in my database.

Comment: Yes 'ContactEmails.IdEmail' is indexed I belive. In other words in order to create that field the email on table Emails has to exist.

Comment: Well, then it sounds like you have a foreign key defined on `ContactEmails.IdEmail`.  But that doesn't necessarily mean that there is an index defined on that column.  Can you verify?

Comment: If you're serious about getting help for this problem, then the correct way to do this is by sharing the generated SQL and the corresponding execution plans. Chances are very high that there is a real solution to your problem (not an in-memory hash set patch), but you have to provide the necessary information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to determine what is slowing down the query if we could see the actual SQL generated by your Linq query. However, I guess that it might have something to do with your `tryGetContact` Func that is not sharing the same context as the main part of the query.

So if I am right, every time you call `tryGetContact(email.Email)` a new complete query will be executed because of this line:

```
var contactEmail = db.ContactEmails.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.IdEmail==email);
```

In that case the `db.ContactEmails` is not part of the join in the SQL query so it is reexecuted each time.

So what I would do is to add another `join` to include the `ContactEmails` on the Linq (and subsequent SQL) query. This should looks like that:

```
var query = from msg in db.Messages
            join email in db.Emails on msg.ToEmail equals email.Email
            join contactEmail in db.ContactEmails on contactEmail.IdEmail equals email.Email
            where msg.Date < "some date" && msg.Date > "some other date" 
            select new
            {
                MessageSubject = msg.Subject,
                ToEmail = email.Email,
                Contact = (contactEmail==null) ? contactEmail.Contact : null,
            };
```

If this doesn't work you might want to execute the `db.ContactEmails` only once for all your `tryGetContact` calls and store the result in a Collection (or HashSet for better performance).

Comment: Am I missing something? But aren't you performing an inner join on `ContactEmails`, effectively filtering out the results if there is no existing contact for an email?

Comment: Yes that is slowing downl things. I will have to store the contacts in a hashset and then do everything in memory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are right sstan but this should be avoided with an outer join. Glad to help Tono Nam!